# Client and Server Authentication By the Same Certificate

Tags: wcf-security

I use the same certificate both for client and service authentication on Wcf with message security. Does it cause any serious vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have the full certification on both the server and client for security reasons. Have a look at this [Server / Client Certs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/02/18/client-certificates-v-s-server-certificates.aspx)